# How to resolve Error in seqeval in NER bert finetuning?

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, named-entity-recognition, evaluation, huggingface-evaluate

I'm trying to finetune a NER model, (BERT/BioBERT) and after first epoch of training, in Evaluation part, I got the following error, Any idea what is wrong?

```
ValueError: Predictions and/or references don't match the expected format.
Expected format: {'predictions': Sequence(feature=Value(dtype='string', id='label'), length=-1, id='sequence'), 
'references': Sequence(feature=Value(dtype='string', id='label'), length=-1, id='sequence')},
Input predictions: [[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], ..., [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]],
Input references: [[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], ..., [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], 
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]]
```

I am using very standard eval function and if I remove the evaluation from trainer, The model trains without any problem and the results are good, but I have little to no metrics.

```py
def compute_metrics(p):
    predictions, labels = p
    predictions = np.argmax(predictions, axis=2)

    true_predictions = [
        [label_list[p] for (p, l) in zip(prediction, label) if l != -100]
        for prediction, label in zip(predictions, labels)
    ]
    true_labels = [
        [label_list[l] for (p, l) in zip(prediction, label) if l != -100]
        for prediction, label in zip(predictions, labels)
    ]

    results = seqeval.compute(predictions=true_predictions, references=true_labels)
    return {
        "precision": results["overall_precision"],
        "recall": results["overall_recall"],
        "f1": results["overall_f1"],
        "accuracy": results["overall_accuracy"],
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As indicated by the error message, the expected `predictions` & `references` should be lists of strings not integers. For `seqeval`, this makes sense, since the `seqeval` metric is concerned with matching entity spans exactly (as indicated by the `B-` & `I-` prefixes of the tags).

So your `label_list` should map label identifiers to label tags, such as `["O", "B-PER", "I-PER", "B-ORG", "I-ORG", "B-LOC", "I-LOC"]`.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested By KurtMica this edit solved my issue, where convert(list) is a function serving as id2label and convert '2'>>'O'. etc

```
def compute_metrics(p):
    predictions, labels = p
    predictions = np.argmax(predictions, axis=2)

    true_predictions = [
        [label_list[p] for (p, l) in zip(prediction, label) if l != -100]
        for prediction, label in zip(predictions, labels)
    ]
    true_labels = [
        [label_list[l] for (p, l) in zip(prediction, label) if l != -100]
        for prediction, label in zip(predictions, labels)
    ]
    true_predictions = [list( map(str,i) ) for i in true_predictions]
    true_predictions = list(convert(i) for i in true_predictions)
    true_labels = [list( map(str,i) ) for i in true_labels]
    true_labels = list(convert(i) for i in true_labels)
    results = seqeval.compute(predictions=true_predictions, references=true_labels)
    return {
        "precision": results["overall_precision"],
        "recall": results["overall_recall"],
        "f1": results["overall_f1"],
        "accuracy": results["overall_accuracy"],
    }
```